# Solr how to indexing file content to multiple field?

Tags: solr

Solr version: 
7.3.0

I want to indexing file and register extracted text to multi field (word splitted field and bi-gram field) for search flexibility.

I wrote below configset, but it does not work, solr indexed only to content_text ,or content_text_bi  (upper defined fmap.content field only)

solrconfig.xml

```
...
  <requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">content_text</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">content_text_bi</str>
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
...
```

schema.xml

```
...
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <!-- docValues are enabled by default for long type so we don't need to index the version field  -->
    <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
    <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />
    <field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="content_text" type="text_ja" indexed="true" stored="true" storeOffsetsWithPositions="false"/>
    <field name="content_text_bi" type="text_ja_bi" indexed="true" stored="true" storeOffsetsWithPositions="false"/>
    <field name="filepath" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="filename" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="storage_id" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" />
...
```

How can I make it work as I want?

Answer (score 2):

I solved to use copyField in schema.xml.
1. Add this line to schema.xml

```
<copyField source="content_text" dest="content_text_bi" />
```

2.and remove this line in in solrconfig.xml

```
<str name="fmap.content">content_text_bi</str>
```